# Regular Expression for extracting English dates

Tags: regex, date, date-format

In the narration field of this dataset that I am working with, I have these kind of entries:

- Dec10
- Jan11
- Jul-Aug10
- Jun09-Oct11
- clothes with shoes June08-Sept11
- Sep-Dec10 tasks to be done

What Regular expression can I use on the above to get this data:

- Dec10
- Jan11
- Jul-Aug10
- Jun09-Oct11
- June08-Sept11
- Sep-Dec10

Edit (In response to Dan): I have tried

- "(jan\d*|feb\d*|mar\d*|apr\d*|may\d*|jun\d*|june\d*|jul\d*|july\d*|aug\d*|sep\d*|sept\d*|oct\d*|nov\d*|dec\d*)"

But this can only pull the **first two entries** successfully viz:

- Dec10
- Jan11
- Jul
- Jun09
- June08
- Sep

Comment: Just edited my question to answer yours

Comment: @drixie Are you absolutely positively sure 100% and would be willing to bet your life that these and these **only** are your date entries?

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:Jan|Feb|...)                 # first month name
[0-9]{2}                        # first two digits
(?:                             # optional:
  -                             #   -
  (?:Jan|Feb|...)               #   second month name
  [0-9]{2}                      #   second two digits
)?
```

Should work.

Hint: You can probably construct this regex from string components so that you don't have to repeat the month names.

Comment: @robermorales: Can't see why it might fail, can you explain that?

Comment: Works fine. but I dont understand your hint.